# Installed Ubuntu 18.04.01 LTS and my screen is flickering/cutting/glitching

Tags: nvidia, display

My screen **flickers/glitches/cuts** whenever I move something on the screen especially when I'm scrolling, or something happens in Firefox (ads that move) here's how it looks

[image] 
Here's a pastebin with my garbo pc info:

```
System:    Host: flint-desktop Kernel: 4.15.0-39-generic x86_64 bits: 64
           Desktop: Gnome 3.28.3 Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Machine:   Device: desktop Mobo: ASRock model: N68C-GS UCC serial: N/A
           BIOS: American Megatrends v: P1.40 date: 08/25/2010
CPU:       Triple core AMD Athlon II X3 450 (-MCP-) cache: 1536 KB
           clock speeds: max: 3200 MHz 1: 3200 MHz 2: 2500 MHz 3: 2500 MHz
Graphics:  Card: NVIDIA C61 [GeForce 7025 / nForce 630a]
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.19.6 ) driver: nouveau
           Resolution: 1920x1080@60.00hz
           OpenGL: renderer: NV4C version: 2.1 Mesa 18.0.5
Audio:     Card NVIDIA MCP61 High Def. Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.15.0-39-generic
Network:   Card: NVIDIA MCP61 Ethernet driver: forcedeth
           IF: enp0s7 state: up speed: 100 Mbps duplex: full
           mac: 00:25:22:82:a6:c4
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 1000.2GB (0.8% used)
           ID-1: /dev/sda model: N/A size: 1000.2GB
Partition: ID-1: / size: 29G used: 7.6G (28%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda5
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 25.0C mobo: N/A
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info:      Processes: 235 Uptime: 15 min Memory: 2173.8/3692.8MB
           Client: Shell (bash) inxi: 2.3.56
```

I tried installing Nvidia drivers with terminal but it keeps on telling me that the nouveau driver is already installed and that I should uninstall but I can't uninstall it.
I think it's a driver issue but I'm not sure.
I installed Ubuntu desktop 18.04.1 LTS.
If you need any more info tell me.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track, trying to use different drivers often fixes such issues, especially with more obscure GPUs. I recommend you first try installing the drivers from the Ubuntu repository, which should do everything for you, allowing you to bypass your current issue with installing. You can find instructions here: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux

Basically run `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` and you are good.